# "RoutingError" and "No route matches..." from Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've worked up to listing 3.5 in the Rails Tutorial: (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#fig-config_directory_rails)

Unfortunately, despite following all the directions up to this point in the book, I can't open "rails-tutorial...c9.io/static_pages/home" The error shows as follows:

```
Started GET "/static_pages/home" for 73.10.170.180 at 2014-12-29 02:18:23 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home"):
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'static_pages/home'
 get 'static_pages/help'
end
```

My application_controller.rb file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

 def hello
   render text: "hello, world!"
 end
end
```

Not quite sure what to make of this; I've attempted to restart the Rails server and also re-did the Chapter 3 tutorial (up to listing 3.5 when the error occurs) to ensure that I wasn't missing anything via the directions.

Thanks all!

Comment: YOu can fix this by changing

Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'static_pages/home"  => "application#hello"
 get 'static_pages/help'  => "application#hello"
end

However this is not the Rails way of doing it. For your use case you need to create a seperate controller as @Mukul has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your static_pages_controller.rb should have home and help in there.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

Add this to your static_pages_controller.rb, restart server and it should work.